# Como deixar espaço entre imagens?

Tags: java, android

Tenho este layout:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**telainicial.xml**

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/ad_linear_layout"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="praias.android.makerapp.com.praias.TelaInicial"
android:background="#ffffff">


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:id="@+id/l1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:id="@+id/l2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:id="@+id/l3"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"></LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Aqui no java eu crio o imageview e o textview e seto a cada linearlayout
**telainicial.java**

```java
            if(l==1){
                layout1.addView(btCategoria);
                layout1.addView(txtCategoria);

                l=2;
            }else if(l==2){
                layout2.addView(btCategoria);
                layout2.addView(txtCategoria);

                l=3;
            }else if(l==3){
                layout3.addView(btCategoria);
                layout3.addView(txtCategoria);

                l=1;
            }
```

Eu usei o `android:layout_marginRight="7dp"` para deixar um espaço entre as imagens de lado. Aí, eu estava querendo deixar um espaço em baixo para o textiew não ficar muito colado a imagem. Tentei usar o `android:layout_marginTop="5dp"` e também o `android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"` para distanciar um pouco, mas nenhum dos dois funcionou.

Observação: Não usei um gridview porque o que eu achei não funcionou para a minha api

**Criação dos botões**

```
TextView txtCategoria = (TextView)LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.text, null);

            final ImageButton btCategoria = (ImageButton) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.button, null);
            btCategoria.setId((int) listenerCategoria.id);
```

**Declaração dos layout**

```
layout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l1);
    layout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l2);
    layout3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l3);
```

**Resolução**

txtCategoria.setPadding(0,0,0,10);

coloquei um serPadding no textviewe coloquei o bottum em 10

Comment: Estas *views* `btCategoria` e `txtCategoria` são criadas programaticamente, sem nenhum *XML*?

Comment: sim , são criadas no cidigo , mais eu acho que ja sei o porque não estou conseguindo deixar um espaço com o `android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"`, porque todas as imagens e textview estão dentro do mesmo layout e eu estou colocando isso no layout ai funcionaria só se eu tivesse um layout debaixo, tem como eu setar esse `layout_bottom` no java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assim como estas duas `views` foram criadas programaticamente, você também pode definir os valores de margem assim:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
llp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 50);
txtCategoria.setLayoutParams(llp);
```

Neste exemplo é definido o valor da margem inferior do `TextView`, assim a próxima inclusão de `ImageView` dentro deste *layout* terá este espaço em cima.

Comment: do jeito que eu uso o lauyout não ta aparecendo esse setMargins

Comment: Como assim? Você pode usar desse jeito mesmo que está. Mostre o que você fez.

Comment: olha la em cima eu tenho 3 linearlayout eu dei um findviewbyid

Comment: os linearlayout eu ja tenho criado no xml , só a imagem e o textview que não

Comment: Consegui , estou colocando la na pergunta o que eu fiz

Comment: Sim, eu sei, mas essa aplicação é para ser feita exatamente neste TextView. Padding funciona sim, mas na prática mesmo o correto é ter margem. O LinearLayout da minha solução não tem a ver com o seu, é só referência para o LayoutParams.